# Research directions in complex differential geometry

Tags: complex-geometry, soft-question

Not sure if my question makes sense. Is there an area in complex geometry that is as analytic as possible? Actually what I wanted to ask is an area in complex geometry that is as non-algebraic as possible.

Surely I know some areas in complex geometry, for example Hodge theory, (hyper)Kahler manifolds, deformation of complex structures, canonical metrics, etc. But I only know the names, and I don't know, and frankly speaking, am afraid of, if working in any one of these areas or others would eventually need to learn a lot of tools from algebraic geometry. Personally I am not a big fan of algebraic geometry, but somehow would like to work in complex geometry if I could find an area I like.

So, you are very welcome to let me know an area in complex geometry you think is analytic. Then I will explore and take a brief look on related papers.

The books by Jean-Pierre Demailly and by Griffiths-Harris are towards more of the differential-geometric side of complex geometry rather than its algebraic side. But I am not sure if these books will tell (or guide) me a research area or direction. So any book or research monograph recommendation that leads to a research area in complex geometry that is as analytic as possible is also very welcome.

For my background, I know a little bit of real differential geometry. The posts I found in mathoverflow that are similar to my question are more like reference request, rather than a research topic request, so I hope it's ok to post my questions.

Comment: I think you should talk to potential advisors rather than random people on the internet. While I have not voted to close, I would not be surprised if this question ended up being closed (and I also think that questions like this never really get good answers here). I also think that it is unwise to insist that you are never going to learn any particular field.  You go where the math leads you -- every time I have insisted that I disliked something, I have eventually been forced to learn it (and so far I have always learned that I actually liked it, once I got over my uninformed prejudices).

Comment: Mathematically, I want to point out that things that are classically considered analytic could be accessed via "algebraic" methods by recent works in condensed mathematics, cf. [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/423610) and [Clausen–Scholze's lecture notes](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/Complex.pdf).

Comment: @AndyPutman I agree with you that questions like this may not get a good answer here. And not sure if there should be something like a wiki page so that every research area in math has a brief description (which would need the contributions of many researchers), so that researchers in other fields could have a rough picture. On the other hand, I cannot say I dislike algebraic geometry, I simply haven't learned it during my graduate study, and it seems I am kind of too old to learn it now (even the basic). Anyway, let see if there is anything which leads me to complex geometry.

Comment: @Z.M Thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: One possible answer to this is geometric analysis, which is quite an active subject indeed. This can be paraphrased as "partial differential equations on manifolds", and a substantial portion of it is intended to have applications to complex geometry. Hodge theory is a good historical example of this, and a more recent topic (that is definitely still an active area of research) is the study of Kähler–Einstein metrics.